# Using third party library in software ag webmethods results in InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, webmethods

I'm using [This Library](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader) in **webmethods** to read from a large .xlsm file, It's a wrapper around Apache POI library. I cannot use the default POI API since the file contains more than 1 million rows and it's just too big to be loaded at once.

so the problem here is that when I import the library in my test project in eclipse (not webmethods) it works perfectly without any problem but when I import it into webmethods with all the required jar files when I run, it throws an "InvocationTargetException".

Here's the class that is used for parsing from that library:

```
package com.monitorjbl.xlsx;

import com.monitorjbl.xlsx.exceptions.CloseException;
import com.monitorjbl.xlsx.exceptions.MissingSheetException;
import com.monitorjbl.xlsx.exceptions.OpenException;
import com.monitorjbl.xlsx.exceptions.ReadException;
import com.monitorjbl.xlsx.impl.StreamingCell;
import com.monitorjbl.xlsx.impl.StreamingRow;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.Decryptor;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BuiltinFormats;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRichTextString;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute;
import javax.xml.stream.events.Characters;
import javax.xml.stream.events.EndElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import static com.monitorjbl.xlsx.XmlUtils.document;
import static com.monitorjbl.xlsx.XmlUtils.searchForNodeList;

/**
 * Streaming Excel workbook implementation. Most advanced features of POI are not supported.
 * Use this only if your application can handle iterating through an entire workbook, row by
 * row.
 */
public class StreamingReader implements Iterable<Row>, AutoCloseable {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StreamingReader.class);

  private final SharedStringsTable sst;
  private final StylesTable stylesTable;
  private final XMLEventReader parser;
  private final DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

  private int rowCacheSize;
  private List<Row> rowCache = new ArrayList<>();
  private Iterator<Row> rowCacheIterator;

  private String lastContents;
  private StreamingRow currentRow;
  private StreamingCell currentCell;

  private File tmp;

  private StreamingReader(SharedStringsTable sst, StylesTable stylesTable, XMLEventReader parser, int rowCacheSize) {
    this.sst = sst;
    this.stylesTable = stylesTable;
    this.parser = parser;
    this.rowCacheSize = rowCacheSize;
  }

  /**
   * Read through a number of rows equal to the rowCacheSize field or until there is no more data to read
   *
   * @return true if data was read
   */
  private boolean getRow() {
    try {
      rowCache.clear();
      while(rowCache.size() < rowCacheSize && parser.hasNext()) {
        handleEvent(parser.nextEvent());
      }
      rowCacheIterator = rowCache.iterator();
      return rowCacheIterator.hasNext();
    } catch(XMLStreamException | SAXException e) {
      log.debug("End of stream");
    }
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Handles a SAX event.
   *
   * @param event
   * @throws SAXException
   */
  private void handleEvent(XMLEvent event) throws SAXException {
    if(event.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS) {
      Characters c = event.asCharacters();
      lastContents += c.getData();
    } else if(event.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
      StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
      String tagLocalName = startElement.getName().getLocalPart();

      if("row".equals(tagLocalName)) {
        Attribute rowIndex = startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("r"));
        currentRow = new StreamingRow(Integer.parseInt(rowIndex.getValue()) - 1);
      } else if("c".equals(tagLocalName)) {
        Attribute ref = startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("r"));

        String[] coord = ref.getValue().split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
        currentCell = new StreamingCell(CellReference.convertColStringToIndex(coord[0]), Integer.parseInt(coord[1]) - 1);
        setFormatString(startElement, currentCell);

        Attribute type = startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("t"));
        if(type != null) {
          currentCell.setType(type.getValue());
        } else {
          currentCell.setType("n");
        }

        Attribute style = startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("s"));

        if(style != null){
          String indexStr = style.getValue();
          try{
            int index = Integer.parseInt(indexStr);
            currentCell.setCellStyle(stylesTable.getStyleAt(index));
          } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            log.warn("Ignoring invalid style index {}", indexStr);
          }
        }
      }

      // Clear contents cache
      lastContents = "";
    } else if(event.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT) {
      EndElement endElement = event.asEndElement();
      String tagLocalName = endElement.getName().getLocalPart();

      if("v".equals(tagLocalName)) {
        currentCell.setRawContents(unformattedContents());
        currentCell.setContents(formattedContents());
      } else if("row".equals(tagLocalName) && currentRow != null) {
        rowCache.add(currentRow);
      } else if("c".equals(tagLocalName)) {
        currentRow.getCellMap().put(currentCell.getColumnIndex(), currentCell);
      }

    }
  }

  /**
   * Read the numeric format string out of the styles table for this cell. Stores
   * the result in the Cell.
   *
   * @param startElement
   * @param cell
   */
  void setFormatString(StartElement startElement, StreamingCell cell) {
    Attribute cellStyle = startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("s"));
    String cellStyleString = (cellStyle != null) ? cellStyle.getValue() : null;
    XSSFCellStyle style = null;

    if(cellStyleString != null) {
      style = stylesTable.getStyleAt(Integer.parseInt(cellStyleString));
    } else if(stylesTable.getNumCellStyles() > 0) {
      style = stylesTable.getStyleAt(0);
    }

    if(style != null) {
      cell.setNumericFormatIndex(style.getDataFormat());
      String formatString = style.getDataFormatString();

      if(formatString != null) {
        cell.setNumericFormat(formatString);
      } else {
        cell.setNumericFormat(BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat(cell.getNumericFormatIndex()));
      }
    } else {
      cell.setNumericFormatIndex(null);
      cell.setNumericFormat(null);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Tries to format the contents of the last contents appropriately based on
   * the type of cell and the discovered numeric format.
   *
   * @return
   */
  String formattedContents() {
    switch(currentCell.getType()) {
      case "s":           //string stored in shared table
        int idx = Integer.parseInt(lastContents);
        return new XSSFRichTextString(sst.getEntryAt(idx)).toString();
      case "inlineStr":   //inline string (not in sst)
        return new XSSFRichTextString(lastContents).toString();
      case "str":         //forumla type
        return '"' + lastContents + '"';
      case "e":           //error type
        return "ERROR:  " + lastContents;
      case "n":           //numeric type
        if(currentCell.getNumericFormat() != null && lastContents.length() > 0) {
          return dataFormatter.formatRawCellContents(
              Double.parseDouble(lastContents),
              currentCell.getNumericFormatIndex(),
              currentCell.getNumericFormat());
        } else {
          return lastContents;
        }
      default:
        return lastContents;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Returns the contents of the cell, with no formatting applied
   *
   * @return
   */
  String unformattedContents() {
    switch(currentCell.getType()) {
      case "s":           //string stored in shared table
        int idx = Integer.parseInt(lastContents);
        return new XSSFRichTextString(sst.getEntryAt(idx)).toString();
      case "inlineStr":   //inline string (not in sst)
        return new XSSFRichTextString(lastContents).toString();
      default:
        return lastContents;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Returns a new streaming iterator to loop through rows. This iterator is not
   * guaranteed to have all rows in memory, and any particular iteration may
   * trigger a load from disk to read in new data.
   *
   * @return the streaming iterator
   */
  @Override
  public Iterator<Row> iterator() {
    return new StreamingIterator();
  }

  /**
   * Closes the streaming resource, attempting to clean up any temporary files created.
   *
   * @throws com.monitorjbl.xlsx.exceptions.CloseException if there is an issue closing the stream
   */
  @Override
  public void close() {
    try {
      parser.close();
    } catch(XMLStreamException e) {
      throw new CloseException(e);
    }

    if(tmp != null) {
      log.debug("Deleting tmp file [" + tmp.getAbsolutePath() + "]");
      tmp.delete();
    }
  }

  static File writeInputStreamToFile(InputStream is, int bufferSize) throws IOException {
    File f = Files.createTempFile("tmp-", ".xlsx").toFile();
    try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f)) {
      int read;
      byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];
      while((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        fos.write(bytes, 0, read);
      }
      is.close();
      fos.close();
      return f;
    }
  }

  public static Builder builder() {
    return new Builder();
  }

  public static class Builder {
    int rowCacheSize = 10;
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    int sheetIndex = 0;
    String sheetName;
    String password;

    /**
     * The number of rows to keep in memory at any given point.
     * <p>
     * Defaults to 10
     * </p>
     *
     * @param rowCacheSize number of rows
     * @return reference to current {@code Builder}
     */
    public Builder rowCacheSize(int rowCacheSize) {
      this.rowCacheSize = rowCacheSize;
      return this;
    }

    /**
     * The number of bytes to read into memory from the input
     * resource.
     * <p>
     * Defaults to 1024
     * </p>
     *
     * @param bufferSize buffer size in bytes
     * @return reference to current {@code Builder}
     */
    public Builder bufferSize(int bufferSize) {
      this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
      return this;
    }

    /**
     * Which sheet to open. There can only be one sheet open
     * for a single instance of {@code StreamingReader}. If
     * more sheets need to be read, a new instance must be
     * created.
     * <p>
     * Defaults to 0
     * </p>
     *
     * @param sheetIndex index of sheet
     * @return reference to current {@code Builder}
     */
    public Builder sheetIndex(int sheetIndex) {
      this.sheetIndex = sheetIndex;
      return this;
    }

    /**
     * Which sheet to open. There can only be one sheet open
     * for a single instance of {@code StreamingReader}. If
     * more sheets need to be read, a new instance must be
     * created.
     *
     * @param sheetName name of sheet
     * @return reference to current {@code Builder}
     */
    public Builder sheetName(String sheetName) {
      this.sheetName = sheetName;
      return this;
    }

    /**
     * For password protected files specify password to open file.
     * If the password is incorrect a {@code ReadException} is thrown on
     * {@code read}.
     * <p>NULL indicates that no password should be used, this is the
     * default value.</p>
     *
     * @param password to use when opening file
     * @return reference to current {@code Builder}
     */
    public Builder password(String password) {
      this.password = password;
      return this;
    }

    /**
     * Reads a given {@code InputStream} and returns a new
     * instance of {@code StreamingReader}. Due to Apache POI
     * limitations, a temporary file must be written in order
     * to create a streaming iterator. This process will use
     * the same buffer size as specified in {@link #bufferSize(int)}.
     *
     * @param is input stream to read in
     * @return built streaming reader instance
     * @throws com.monitorjbl.xlsx.exceptions.ReadException if there is an issue reading the stream
     */
    public StreamingReader read(InputStream is) {
      File f = null;
      try {
        f = writeInputStreamToFile(is, bufferSize);
        log.debug("Created temp file [" + f.getAbsolutePath() + "]");

        StreamingReader r = read(f);
        r.tmp = f;
        return r;
      } catch(IOException e) {
        throw new ReadException("Unable to read input stream", e);
      } catch(RuntimeException e) {
        f.delete();
        throw e;
      }
    }

    /**
     * Reads a given {@code File} and returns a new instance
     * of {@code StreamingReader}.
     *
     * @param f file to read in
     * @return built streaming reader instance
     * @throws com.monitorjbl.xlsx.exceptions.OpenException if there is an issue opening the file
     * @throws com.monitorjbl.xlsx.exceptions.ReadException if there is an issue reading the file
     */
    public StreamingReader read(File f) {
      try {
        OPCPackage pkg;

        if(password != null) {
          // Based on: https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html
          POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem(f);
          EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(poifs);
          Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);
          d.verifyPassword(password);
          pkg = OPCPackage.open(d.getDataStream(poifs));
        } else {
          pkg = OPCPackage.open(f);
        }

        XSSFReader reader = new XSSFReader(pkg);
        SharedStringsTable sst = reader.getSharedStringsTable();
        StylesTable styles = reader.getStylesTable();

        InputStream sheet = findSheet(reader);
        if(sheet == null) {
          throw new MissingSheetException("Unable to find sheet at index [" + sheetIndex + "]");
        }

        XMLEventReader parser = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(sheet);
        return new StreamingReader(sst, styles, parser, rowCacheSize);
      } catch(IOException e) {
        throw new OpenException("Failed to open file", e);
      } catch(OpenXML4JException | XMLStreamException e) {
        throw new ReadException("Unable to read workbook", e);
      } catch(GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw new ReadException("Unable to read workbook - Decryption failed", e);
      }
    }

    InputStream findSheet(XSSFReader reader) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
      int index = sheetIndex;
      if(sheetName != null) {
        index = -1;
        //This file is separate from the worksheet data, and should be fairly small
        NodeList nl = searchForNodeList(document(reader.getWorkbookData()), "/workbook/sheets/sheet");
        for(int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
          if(Objects.equals(nl.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getTextContent(), sheetName)) {
            index = i;
          }
        }
        if(index < 0) {
          return null;
        }
      }
      Iterator<InputStream> iter = reader.getSheetsData();
      InputStream sheet = null;

      int i = 0;
      while(iter.hasNext()) {
        InputStream is = iter.next();
        if(i++ == index) {
          sheet = is;
          log.debug("Found sheet at index [" + sheetIndex + "]");
          break;
        }
      }
      return sheet;
    }
  }

  class StreamingIterator implements Iterator<Row> {
    public StreamingIterator() {
      if(rowCacheIterator == null) {
        hasNext();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      return (rowCacheIterator != null && rowCacheIterator.hasNext()) || getRow();
    }

    @Override
    public Row next() {
      return rowCacheIterator.next();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
      throw new RuntimeException("NotSupported");
    }
  }

}
```

and here is the code I use in my java service: (it's basically what the library provides in their page as documentation)

```
File is = new File("E:\\bpc\\testdata01.xlsm"));
StreamingReader reader = StreamingReader.builder()
        .rowCacheSize(100)    
        .bufferSize(4096)     
        .sheetName("SOURCE_1")  
        .read(is);
```

so when the **StreamingReader** calls read(is) function I get the below exception thrown:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader
```

I'm really sure why is it happening like this... is it because the builder class in the source code is static and it's being called from my static java service?

**Note:** Please be noted that I'm running this software AG webmethods and it's has its own way of implementing a java service so the only place that I can put my code in is like this: **(you cannot debug the java service)**

```
public final class importInputFile_SVC
{

    public static final void importInputFile(IData pipeline)
                throws ServiceException {
        //code goes here
    }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Unable to understand your question regarding the library. 
But, regarding the large size file, did you try loading the file as stream and then use node iterator feature?
That would considerably reduce the size of the file and would help with better performance.

Comment: You **can** [debug java service](http://tech.forums.softwareag.com/techjforum/posts/list/45098.page) and also this [video](http://techcommunity.softwareag.com/download/webMethods/esb/demos/editing_debugging_java_services/player.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not enough information for really analyzing your problem. But try putting all libraries in your package's code/jars directory and enable the package classloader in the manifest.v3 file. This will ensure that your java service uses only your specific libs and not jars on other version which may be part of your wM installation.

**Edit**: Enable the package classloader in the manifest.v3 file by adding the following line:

```
<value name='classloader'>package</value>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, may I know what xml attribute is that enables the package classloader in the manifest file? By the way, I'm not sure what other information I can provide since that's all the information I had. do you need the list of the jars I loaded?

Comment: Yup that's true. I've got it from the SAG consultant but yet your answer will be marked as the right one :) cheers